# Setter injection on an existing service instance in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Does Castle Windsor support applying setter injection to existing service instances? I have a case in which I have no control over the creation of certain class instances while I do need to resolve dependencies for them. This rules out constructor injection but leaves the door open for setter injection since I can intercept the new instances right after they're created.

I know Castle Windsor supports setter injection out of the box, I just don't know whether its possible (and if so: how) to leverage it explicitly without using the `Resolve` method.

I know as well that such thing is possible in StructureMap, using the `ObjectFactory.BuildUp` method so that raises my hope of finding an equivalent in Castle Windsor.

In case you are wondering, I'm applying dependency injection to pages in ASP.NET WebForms, providing a custom `PageHandlerFactory`. I don't want to go down the path of trying to create the page handler myself, I should leave that to the base implementation in the `PageHandlerFactory` class.

```
public class CustomPageHandlerFactory : PageHandlerFactory
{
    public override IHttpHandler GetHandler(HttpContext context, string requestType, string virtualPath, string path)
    {
        IHttpHandler handler = base.GetHandler(context, requestType, virtualPath, path);
        Page page = handler as Page;

        if (page == null)
        {
            return handler;
        }

        // Resolve dependencies using setter injection...

        return page;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the bottom of this article:

http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2008/11/08/dependency-injection-with-aspnet-mvc-action-filters/

Jeremy provides an extension method for the Windsor Container that implements property injection.

Comment: Thanks. The provided code implements the injection instead of leaving it up to Windsor and is not very performant due to the reflection code and the absence of a caching mechanism. I'll stick it into my code base as a temporary solution though, until I have a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Castle Windsor support applying setter injection to existing service instances?

No. Check out the [FAQ](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.FAQ.ashx#Why_cant_Windsor_resolve_concrete_types_without_registering_them_first_11) for rationale.

> I'm applying dependency injection to pages in ASP.NET WebForms,

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491400/dependency-injection-gotchas).

Comment: I see. I'm thinking of writing a facility that uses a lazy component loader to do the setter injection. I know it's all a bit smelly but I think that's inevitable when using ASP.NET WebForms.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Neal Shawn's [ASpNetWindsorModule](http://code.google.com/p/sneal/wiki/AspNetWindsorModule).

Comment: Thanks, that module is really neat!

Comment: I just wish it supported setter injection for user controls.

Comment: It does support that. Only when you use LoadControl() yourself it will not work OOTB.

Comment: That's indeed what I am using. Wrapping `LoadControl` quickly solves that though.